# API call to update a field of an object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have an model serializer which consists of

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
```

This is my ViewSet

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

This is my URLs.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('user', views.UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^login/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Using the serializer, I can make it print out the objects inside my database. If I have the object PK/ID, I want to be able to update the field `id` or `name` of the object. Is there a way I can do that with a patch/post request using the serializer? I'm new to this so I'd love it if someone can help me out with this.

I'm thinking of just doing a `POST` request, then have it do this:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=id)
user.name = "XXXXX"
user.save()
```

But I want to do this using the serializer, using a `PATCH` request.

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question? If not, did you run into issues?

Answer (score 0):

the below code will help to you,

```
**filename : views.py**

from user.models import User
from users.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class UserList(APIView):
    """
    List all users, or create a new user.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class UserDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a user instance.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


**filename : urls.py**

from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from users import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**Reference :** http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework comes with some pre-defined [concrete generic views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes) such as `UpdateAPIView`, `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`.

First you need to create a view for `user` which uses one of the views which can `update`. The update views provides handlers for `patch` method on the view.

> **[RetrieveUpdateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview)**
>
> Used for read or update endpoints to represent a single model instance.
>
> Provides `get`, `put` and `patch` method handlers.

Now, use this to create a view:

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

To access this view you need to have a url which uses user's primary key to access the user:

```
url(r'users/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserDetail.as_view(), name='api-user-detail'),
```

Then using PATCH call you can update the user's `name`.

Comment: I think your code would work, but OP's code uses a ModelViewset, which provides update capability by default: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: I agree, both `generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView` and `ModelViewSet` use `mixins.UpdateModelMixin`. So I think the only thing OP need is a url with `pk` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `ModelViewset`, this capability should be built in. If you use the browsable API to navigate to `/user/<pk>/`, you'll see the operations you can perform on that object. By default, a ModelViewset provides `list()`, `retrieve()`, `create()`, `update()`, and `destroy()` capability.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

You can also override any or all of the provided methods, however an update of a single object is built in to DRF ModelViewsets. Use curl to try a PATCH to `/user/<pk>/` with the information you'd like to update.